# Mongodb taking high memory in server, the only change that has gone is addition of one index in one table with around 800 entries

Tags: mongodb, memory-management

Mongodb taking high memory in server, the only change that has gone is addition of one index in one table with around 800 entries. The mongo slows down while persisting the data on the collection which has got one additional index. Mongo version is 2.6.4 and Spring Data has been used in the application to interact with mongo.

Comment: what type of server configuration is this? What is the data size? Have you checked mongostat output if there are any locks and queues?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if this will resolve your issue but this could be of help.

MongoDB seems to use up a lot of available memory, but it's actually not. Its upto OS to release the memory caching

**You can simply release the memory by restarting the MongoDB. It helped in my case.**

> Depending on the platform you may see the mapped files as memory in
>   the process, but this is not strictly correct.
>
> It is called "cached" memory.

You can read more on this [**HERE**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#faq-memory)

If the above solution doesn't help. Read this (Haven't tried)

[**Reclaiming memory from MongoDB Indexes**](https://blog.serverdensity.com/reclaiming-memory-from-mongodb-indexes/)

Comment: We already have restarted he server but within a day it went back to high memory again.